# How to switch between columns in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs

Using [Google Docs](https://docs.google.com), I went to Format>Columns to divide my document into two columns, but I'm stuck on the first column and don't know how to jump to the other one to start editing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my answer [here](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/6742495?hl=en&msgid=6767284).

It says that Google Docs columns works in such way that the document gets split up into two columns, meaning that the current text keeps its continuous flow until the rest of the page, and then moves back to the second column.
To facilitate two separate columns, a table should be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually determine a manual column break by selecting "Insert" > "Break" > "Column Break". The text will break to the next column based on where your cursor is currently positioned.